# extension manager GUI not opening in wayland_22.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, wayland, 22.04

I realized that the GUI for the extension manager won't open while in wayland, however, is working while in X11. I get an error message as shown;

`Gdk-Message: 23:41:01.022: Error reading events from display: Protocol error`

I tried using Extensions list as a work around which only allows  to toggling between on/off, however, can't access the settings of the extensions.
Kindly advise

Answer (score 5):

This https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1965563 seems related. I'm having the same issue and it appears to happen with wayland session specifically after installing nvidia-510 drivers.It was functional prior to it.